# Vsphere: Designate Specific folder for VMS inside Datastore

Tags: storage, vmware-vsphere, datastore, vsphere-client

I have a single ISCSI LUN connected to my ESXI host which is used as a VMFS datastore. Is it possible to have vms created inside of a specific folder inside that datastore by default? I have tried using storage policies in Vcenter, but it looks like you can only add tags to datastores and not files/folders inside.

The end goal would be to have something like the following be the default behavior:

- Templates created with Packer get automatically sent to **Templates** folder inside the datastore
- VMs created with Terraform or manually get automatically sent to **VMs** folder inside the datastore

I know you can create logical separations in Vcenter, but I would really like to have things organized at the datastore level. Is this just not possible or do most people just use multiple datastores in this case (not really a good option for me)?

**Environment**

- ESXI 7.0
- Vcenter 7.0
- 1 ISCI LUN

Comment: Why is the datastore location or hierarchy important to you? (e.g. what is the reasoning behind the issue you're presenting?)

Comment: Really just a matter of preference. I'd like to keep templates, vms, and other in separate folders for ease of management. With packer/terraform I might spin up and destroy many vms/templates in a day and do not want to manually move these files.

**EDIT - Additionally I'm using vsphere to provision kubernetes persistent volumes which I would like to put into their own folders etc.

Comment: I'm not gonna tell you that this certainly can't be done, but I've never heard of it, generally people leave vSphere up to it's own devices when it comes to organising the folder structure of datastores. Hence it might be hard to find any information regarding this. If you have support (which I'm guessing you do since you're running vCenter), I'd ask this from VMware directly.

Comment: Ok. Well that's unfortunate but I can live with it. Thanks for your answer :).